# Editing data in linked list error : no match for operator==

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a room booking system. The code i'm working on is the function for editing the room type details. It's going to ask the user to enter the room ID and pass it to `edit_room()` function to edit the room type details.

This is my `struct`:

```
struct Node{
    ListItemType roomType;
    ListItemType id;

    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};

Node *head;
Node *tail;
```

And this is the function for editing the room type:

```
void edit_room(int edit)
{
    ListItemType roomType, roomType1, roomType2;

    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        bool found = false;

        Node* curr = new Node;
        curr = head;

        while(curr != tail->next)
        {
            if(edit == curr->id)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        if(found)
        {
            cout << "Enter New Room Type Name: " << endl;
            cout << " ";
            cin >> roomtype1;
            getline(cin,roomtype2);
            roomtype = roomtype1 + roomtype2;

            curr->roomType = roomtype;
            cout << endl << "Successfully updated." << endl << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
        else
            cout << "Could not update information. " << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I got an error:

> `'error: no match for 'operator==' in 'edit == curr->List::Node::id'.`

What does this error mean and how should I fix it?

Comment: You're comparing an int to a ListItemType. Did you define the == operator for ListItemType?

Comment: no, i didn't. here is my implementation of ListItemType:
typedef string ListItemType;

Comment: @user3182797: Then the implementation in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21058897/78845) should help you!

Comment: @Johnsyweb sorry i sounds annoying, but i tried what you told me, but i got an error, "error: 'bool List::operator==(int, const ListItemType&)' must take exactly one argument".

Comment: This is a free function, not a member of your `List` `class`

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the compiler did not find operator-== that compares an object of type int with an object of type ListItemType. Simply the compiler does not know how to compare them. You did not show us how type ListItemType is defined,

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListItemType` implementation is key to answering this question.

If it's not just `typedef`ed to `int`, then you're going to need to implement an `operator ==()` to compare `int` to `ListItemType`. It would look a little like this:

```
bool operator ==(int lhs, ListItemType const& rhs)
{
    return lhs == std::stoi(rhs);
}
```

Perhaps you'd better adjusting the signature of `void edit_room(int edit)` to:

```
void edit_room(ListItemType& item)
```

You may also be better off just using [`std::list<ListItemType>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) rather than implement your own link-list (this is a solved problem)!

#### Note

Watch out for your capitalisation in `roomType`. You have `roomtype` later in the function, which will not compile.